# Docking station : 2 monitors

Tags: display, docking-station

I have a laptop connected to a docking station and in addition to the laptop there are two monitors.

The problem is that when I have the laptop open, the 2 additional screens are black. They are detected in the control panel.

If I close the laptop, the 2 monitors work.

How can I make it possible that three screens work at the same time?

Thanks,

Kat

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried messing with your projector settings via Win+P?

It may be set to computer only. Try setting to extend(most likely what you are looking for if you want to use all three screens).